# android jetpack compose, update text output composable that receives text from a "global variable", statechange detect

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

in my app i use a global string-variable that receives status information from more than one activity.

in my Mainactivitys screen composables, there is a text-field that reads that global variable and displays its string.

So:

```
//global string var getting updated from other activitys to display a statustext
var statustext = "init string" 

MainActivity (){
...
  oncreate...
...
    OutlinedTextField(
                            value = statustext,   // display text on main screen
                            onValueChange = {},
                            label = { Text("Status") },
                            minLines = 20,
                            maxLines = 20,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .wrapContentHeight()
                                //.padding(16.dp)
                        )
}
```

It works only once when Oncreate executes.

So i need to implement a changedetection for Compose.

i am reading to use a viewmodel.

What is the simplest method to implement statedetection here?

var statustext = mutableStateOf("") ?

i tryd: var statustext = mutableStateOf("")
then in composable:
value = statustext.value

didnt work

Answer (score 1):

answering my own question:

```
var statustext by mutableStateOf("init string") // thats all i needed 
// the "init string" makes statustext a String variable

MainActivity (){
...
  oncreate...
...
    OutlinedTextField(
                            value = statustext,   // display text on main screen
                            onValueChange = {},
                            label = { Text("Status") },
                            minLines = 20,
                            maxLines = 20,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .wrapContentHeight()
                                //.padding(16.dp)
                        )
}
```

using the "by" keyword enables "statustext" to be still usable as a String var.
So can be updated throughout my activitys (global context).
No viewmodel or Flows.
So using mutableStateOf() in global context is working in my app.
(magicly ;)